# Assign to a reference of a more generic type

Tags: java, generics, lambda, java-8

Is there any way I can reference this::method using a more generic type like below?

```
Number method(Integer input){ return 1;}

void test(){
    Function<Integer, Number> ref = this::method; //OK
    Function<Number, Number> moreGenericRef = this::method // does not compile.
    Function<? extends Number, Number> moreGenericRef2 = this::method // does not compile.
}
```

I want to be able to do the following.

```
Map<String, Function<Number,Number>> maps;
maps.add("method1", this::method)
maps.add("method2", this::method2)

maps.get("methods1").apply(1.2);
maps.get("methods2").apply(1);
```

The functions are adapters that will be called by the mapper of Stream< Number >

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is PECS (Producer Extends Consumer Super)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/what-is-pecs-producer-extends-consumer-super)

Comment: No. You can't pass any `Number` to a method expecting `Integer`.

Comment: if you change your method like this `Number method(Number input){ return 1;}` , then all three compiles

Comment: @pvpkiran but then method won't' have access to the methods inside Integer.class, unless I explicitly downcast.

Comment: The real mistake is that you think you need this. You might want to describe your actual requirement, instead of presenting us with an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info).

Comment: @shmosel I want to store the functions as values in a map in an abstract class, and later accessed by its subclasses via, say, a string key.

Comment: @dwong: that's correct, and that's how it _should_ be.  If you "need access to the methods inside Integer.class" then you don't actually _have_ a `Function<Number, Number>`, and no amount of shenanigans will change that.  The Java compiler is doing the right thing here.

Comment: @shmosel all the functions/methods have similar behavior and the input extends the same superclass. I want to write the code more abstractly so that it will execute a function in the map by passing the input's superclass type.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Thanks for your answer. The access to methods in Integer.class will happen only inside "method." I have updated my description with my requirements. I probably can work around by changing my design, but i am wondering if I could achieve what i wanted.

Comment: It doesn't matter that it only occurs inside method.  This has nothing to do with lambdas, really.  You can't implement a method that takes an arbitrary Number by passing it to method.

Answer (score 2):

You'd need the argument of the function to be *contravariant* instead of *covariant*:

```
Function<? super Integer, ? extends Number> moreGenericRef2 = this::method;
```

This compiles fine, and also allows for the return type to be any descendant of `Number`.

See [PECS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/what-is-pecs-producer-extends-consumer-super), which stands for Producer Extends, Consumer Super. See also [covariance and contravariance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)) for an in-depth introduction of this subject.

Comment: thanks for your answer; however, it doesn't compile


    `incompatible types: invalid method reference
Function<? super Number, ? extends Number> moreGenericRef2 =  this::method;
                                                                  ^
    incompatible types: Number cannot be converted to Integer`

Comment: True, but it's not clear that OP has such a method or was trying to assign it.

Answer (score 2):

Well if you change the definition to:

```
Function<? extends Integer, ? extends Number> moreGenericRef2 = this::method;
```

*or*

```
Function<Integer, ? extends Number> moreGenericRef2 = this::method;
```

*or*

```
Function<Integer, Number> moreGenericRef2 = this::method;
```

But having a definition such as `? extends Integer` (where `Integer` is a final class makes no sense anyway)

Comment: `Function<? extends Integer,` is a useless definition. May as well use `Function<?,`.

Comment: @tsolakp It'll compile, but it's (almost) useless, like I said.

Comment: @shmosel. It wont even compile.

Comment: @tsolakp Hmm, you're right, but that seems to be a failure of type inference. This works, for example: `Function<?, Number> ref = (Function<Integer, Number>)this::method;`